# Nearby Connections API: Unstable Connectivity in Long-Running Mesh Network

Tags: android, kotlin, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I'm using the Nearby Connections API for an operation app that requires high availability. However, I'm experiencing inconsistent behavior over extended periods (days or months). The app sometimes loses connectivity between devices and only recovers after restarting the main router.

Setup:

Mesh strategy with one advertiser and several discoverers (total of 9 devices).
Single router with 4 access points (range extenders).
Static IPs for all devices and access points.
DHCP disabled on all access points.
MAC addresses reserved on the router.

Tried various network configurations:

Running on router only.
Using fewer access points.
Swapping router and access points.
Restarted devices, apps, and access points.
Confirmed network functionality (internet access, ping to router/access points).

Observations:

Devices automatically reconnect after short disconnects(as expected after disconnect).

Sudden and persistent connection loss requires restarting the main router.
Internet access remains functional while Nearby Connections fails.

What could be causing this unstable connectivity? Is there a known issue with Nearby Connections for long-running mesh networks? Any suggestions for further troubleshooting or potential solutions?

Comment: am facing the same problem :(